# How can I make my character move with the speed of the Log when it's on it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development

I'm making a game like of CrossyRoad. When my character hops on a log I want it to move WITH the log at the same speed. I can't make the player stay on the log. Both objects have colliders and rigidbody with gravity

I have tried making the log parent of the player on Collison, but nothing.

`

```
private Animator animator;
private bool isHopping;

public float moveSpeed = 5f;
private Transform objectTransform;
private bool shouldHop; // Flag to indicate if the player should hop

private void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    objectTransform = transform.GetChild(0);
    terrainGenerator = FindObjectOfType<TerrainGenerator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Check for any of the movement keys being pressed
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) && !isHopping)
    {
        shouldHop = true; // Set the hop flag whenever any of the movement keys are pressed
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (shouldHop && !isHopping)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hop");
        isHopping = true;
        shouldHop = false; // Reset the hop flag after setting the hop animation



        score++;
        Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
    }

    if (isHopping)
    {
        // Calculate the movement vector based on the pressed keys
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(verticalInput, 0f, -horizontalInput).normalized * moveSpeed *      Time.deltaTime;

        // Apply the movement
        objectTransform.Translate(movement, Space.World);
    }
    
}

public void FinishHop()
{
    isHopping = false;

    // Snap the player position to terrain block size (X1) after hopping
    float newX = Mathf.Round(objectTransform.position.x);
    float newZ = Mathf.Round(objectTransform.position.z);
    objectTransform.position = new Vector3(newX, objectTransform.position.y, newZ);

    terrainGenerator.SpawnTerrain(false, objectTransform.position);
     }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Log logComponent = collision.collider.GetComponent<Log>();
    if (logComponent != null && logComponent.isLog)
    {
        transform.parent = collision.collider.transform;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    Log logComponent = collision.collider.GetComponent<Log>();
    if (logComponent != null && logComponent.isLog)
    {
        transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

}`

and the log script

Comment: What exactly happens when you make the player a child of the log wdym by its not working